# Is there a way to change the default paths for visualstudiocode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Settings, plugins are held in these predefined locations, for example on Windows it's

%APPDATA%\Code\

It is possible to override this path and maybe set it relative to the installation or working directory?

Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code supports Portable Mode, which will keep data in folders local to the installation.

You can refer to the documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/docs/editor/portable.md) for how to configure it.

Comment: creating data folder to enable it, that is neat

Answer (score 3):

Just as a reference if someone finds this issue again:

There is a command line option to set the data folder: `--user-data-dir <dir>`

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_advanced-cli-options

Comment: Great the things evolve over the time